Outer delay in stream to stream join in structured streaming
Reading from Structured Streaming Programming Guide
"In the current implementation in the micro-batch engine, watermarks are advanced at the end of a micro-batch, and the next micro-batch uses the updated watermark to clean up state and output outer results. Since we trigger a micro-batch only when there is new data to be processed, the generation of the outer result may get delayed if there no new data being received in the stream. In short, if any of the two input streams being joined does not receive data for a while, the outer (both cases, left or right) output may get delayed."
How long is it delayed if there are no new data in one of the streams?
At the moment, the output stops, no matter how long I wait.

My current implementation I'm using spark.conf.set('spark.sql.streaming.multipleWatermarkPolicy', 'max'), which obviously moves the watermark, but it is not what I wanted. Anyway, it needs spark 3.x.
